# Error on calling Javascript APIs within Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-applications

I am currently building a web extension and in the stage of porting between browsers. On moving from Chrome to Firefox I am coming against an issue in using the runtime.sendMessage API that allows me to talk between the content and background scripts.

The message code in the content script:

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage('d089938d-ba63-4c40-98ab-b8515db1bbca', { greeting: "screenshot-please" }, function (response) {
    localStorage.setItem("image", response.farewell);
});
var image = localStorage.getItem("image");
```

The Background script:

```
var img = saved-image;
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.greeting === "screenshot-please"){
      sendResponse({
        farewell: img
      });
    }       
  }
);
```

and the manifest:

```
{
  "description": "...",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "...",
  "permissions": [
    "find",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
                 "id": "..."
        }
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["/JavaScript/moz-initialPopup.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
      "all_frames": true,
            "matches": ["*://127.0.0.1:3000/*"],
            "js": ["Javascript/dataGrab.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "48": "..."
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_title": "...",
    "default_icon": {
        "48": "..."
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

When in chrome (replace all instances of *browser with *chrome) this messaging system works fine. When in firefox, in the developer tools I get 'ReferenceError: browser is not defined'.

Can anyone assist me in why I would not be able to access the browser here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `browser` is chrome-extension-specific

Comment: Just keep using `chrome`. It works in Firefox.

Comment: @zevee Nope, `browser` does not exist in Chrome. It exists in Firefox and Edge, as far as I know. The difference between `browser` and `chrome` is basically `browser` uses promises and `chrome` uses callbacks on Firefox.

Comment: oh. Good to know

Comment: @revilheart when I switch to chrome.runtime.sendMessage() the debugger says chrome is not defined

Comment: @JamesMorton Not sure what's going on then.